# How can I specify an intent filter to recognize jpg files, but not jpeg in Android?

Tags: android, android-intent, mime-types, intentfilter

Basically, I want my app to be able to open *JPG* or *jpg* files, but not files with the file extension *JPEG* or *jpeg*. This is what I have for intent filters, but it is also accepting *JPEG* and *jpeg*:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <data android:scheme="content" android:mimeType="application/octet-stream" android:pathPattern=".*\\.jpg" />
    <data android:scheme="file" android:mimeType="application/octet-stream" android:pathPattern=".*\\.jpg" />
</intent-filter>
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <data android:scheme="file" android:pathPattern=".*\\.jpg" />
</intent-filter>
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <data android:scheme="content" android:mimeType="application/octet-stream" android:pathPattern=".*\\.JPG" />
    <data android:scheme="file" android:mimeType="application/octet-stream" android:pathPattern=".*\\.JPG" />
</intent-filter>
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <data android:scheme="file" android:pathPattern=".*\\.JPG" />
</intent-filter>
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
    <data android:mimeType="image/jpg" android:pathPattern=".*\\.jpg"/>
</intent-filter>
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
    <data android:mimeType="image/jpg" android:pathPattern=".*\\.JPG"/>
</intent-filter>
```

How can I improve this intent filter to handle only specific image file extensions?

Answer (score 1):

You're capturing JPEG images because you specified the `android:mimeType` of `image/jpg`, which JPEG images fit. Remove that tag from your `<data>` element and just specify `android:pathPattern`.